# Bootstrap 4 nav-justified doesn't work properly in IE 11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using IE 11. the following code doesn't work properly in IE 11. It will look like this: 
[image]

This code works perfectly in Firefox:
[image]

However, bootstrap claimed that they are supporting IE 10 and IE 11. So I suspect there are some issues with my customized css code.

Here is the source code for css and html (Razor)

```css
.wizard-step p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.wizard-step button[disabled] {
  color: gray;
}

.wizard-row:before {
  top: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.wizard-step {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: auto
}

.progress {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  height: 7px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 18.5px;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="formWizard" class="wizard">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
      <a id="tab_start" class="nav-link active btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step1" title="Step 1">1</a>
      <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Start report</p>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
      <a id="tab_report" class="nav-link disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step2" title="Step 2">2</a>
      <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Report payroll</p>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
      <a id="tab_review" class="nav-link disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step3" title="Step 3">3</a>
      <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Review and submit</p>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
      <a id="tab_confirm" class="nav-link disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-4" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step4" title="Step 4">4</a>
      <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Print confirmation</p>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
      <a id="tab_pay" class="nav-link disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-5" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step5" title="Step 5">5</a>
      <p class="d-none d-sm-block">View balance or pay</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with `display: table-cell`.  Is this necessary? There's no parent "table".

Comment: You're right. there is no `table`. Remove this attribute works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I suspect there are some issues with my customized css code.

That is correct. I went ahead and commented out some of your custom css in the snippet below and replaced some of your custom css with native Bootstrap classes (see my comments in the code).

Now, my IE11 displays everything properly.

Lesson: Do as much as possible with native Bootstrap classes and use custom css only for stuff that can't be handled with Bootstrap classes.

Here's the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<style>
    .wizard-step p {
/*        margin-top: 10px;*/
/*        replaced with `mt-2` */
    }

    .wizard-step button[disabled] {
        color: gray;
    }

    .wizard-row:before {
/*
        top: 14px;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        content: " ";
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #ccc;
*/
    }

    .btn-circle {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
/*        text-align: center;*/
        padding: 6px 0;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.428571429;
        border-radius: 16px;
    }

    .wizard-step {
/*        display: table-cell;*/
/*        text-align: center;*/
        position: relative;
    }

    .nav-link {
/*        margin: auto*/
/*        replaced with `mx-auto` */
    }

    .progress {
        background-color: #d3d3d3;
        height: 7px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 18.5px;
    }

    .progress-bar {
        background-color: orange;
    }
</style>

<div id="formWizard" class="wizard mt-4">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center nav-justified">
        <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
            <a id="tab_start" class="nav-link mx-auto active btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step1" title="Step 1">1</a>
            <p class="d-none d-sm-block mt-2">Start report</p>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
            <a id="tab_report" class="nav-link mx-auto disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step2" title="Step 2">2</a>
            <p class="d-none d-sm-block mt-2">Report payroll</p>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
            <a id="tab_review" class="nav-link mx-auto disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step3" title="Step 3">3</a>
            <p class="d-none d-sm-block mt-2">Review and submit</p>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
            <a id="tab_confirm" class="nav-link mx-auto disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-4" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step4" title="Step 4">4</a>
            <p class="d-none d-sm-block mt-2">Print confirmation</p>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item wizard-step">
            <a id="tab_pay" class="nav-link mx-auto disabled btn btn-primary btn-circle" href="#tabs-5" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="step5" title="Step 5">5</a>
            <p class="d-none d-sm-block mt-2">View balance or pay</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful @WebDevBooster. My code looks cleaner now. Thanks for the advice. I'll make good use of the Bootstrap v4 spacing classes.